# When to Use Nexenta or OpenFiler or GlusterFS

Tags: storage, openfiler, nexenta

I am not an expert in storage solution and I ma eager to understand the big picture when choosing Storage OS like when we choose to Nexentastor or OpenFiler or GlusterFS

Those three apps are only the example since from my understanding each has its own characters that can be bound together

If anyone here can give further explanation I will be very grateful

Comment: This is way too open a question - can you focus it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openfiler is good if you need an iSCSI or feature-rich NAS storage solution on a single machine with direct storage. Something like Gluster is good when you have an array of machines and you need to store the data across multiple servers. This is better for write-only operations as reads can be much slower.

Comment: Which one does your last statement apply to? Gluster?

Comment: Yes, Gluster. Its available as either an entire storage platform with web management, or just the FS for those who simply need it to interact with other things like Eucalyptus